# Maximum bitstream size for H.264

Tags: h.264, encode, nvidia

Although I am quite familiar with H.264 encoding I came down to a point where I need advice from more experienced people. I'm performing hardware accelerated H.264 encoding using Intel Quick Sync and NVIDIA NVENC in a unified pipeline. The issue that troubles me is bitstream output buffer size. Intel Quick Sync provides a way to query the maximum bitstream size from the encoder, while NVDIA NVENC does not have such a feature (or at least I haven't found it, pointers are welcome). In their tutorial they state that:

> NVIDIA recommends setting the VBV buffer size equal to single frame size. This is very
> helpful in low latency applications, where network bandwidth is a concern. Single frame
> VBV allows users to enable capped frame size encoding. In single frame VBV, VBV
> buffer size must be set to maximum frame size which is equal to channel bitrate divided
> by frame rate. With this setting, every frame can be sent to client immediately upon
> encoding and the decoder can also decode without any buffering.
>
> For example, if you have a channel bitrate of B bits/sec and you are encoding at N fps,
> the following settings are recommended to enable single frame VBV buffer size.
>
> ```
> uint32_t maxFrameSize = B/N;
> NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::vbvBufferSize= maxFrameSize;
> NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::vbvInitialDelay= maxFrameSize;
> NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::maxBitRate= NV_ENC_CONFIG::vbvBufferSize *N; // where N is the encoding frame rate.
> NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::averageBitRate= NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::vbvBufferSize *N; // where N is the encoding frame rate.
> NV_ENC_RC_PARAMS::rateControlMode= NV_ENC_PARAMS_RC_TWOPASS_CBR;
> ```

I am allocating a bitstream buffer pool for quite many encoding sessions so having an overhead of unused memory for each buffer by calculating the size from network bandwidth (in my case it is not the bottleneck) will cause ineffective memory usage.

So the general question is - is there any way how to determine the bitstream size for H.264 assuming there is no frame buffering and each frame should generate NAL units? Can I assume that it will never be larger than the input NV12 buffer (which seems unreliable since there may be many NAL units like SPS/PPS/AUD/SEI for the first frame and I am not sure if the size of those plus the same of IDR frame is not greater than the NV12 buffer size)? Does the standard have any pointers on this? Or is it totally encoder dependent?